# How to get all elements of a column in a list format in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(0111,0112,1124,2389,3480,0134))

ID
0111
0112
1124
2389
3480
0134
```

How can I get all these values in what I think it is a list format?
I need to obtain the following output:

```
0111;0112:1124;2389;3480;0134
```

Comment: That just looks one long string. Do you want this? `paste0(df$ID, collapse = ';')`

Comment: @RonakShah thats exactly what I want! Thanks a lot! Do you want to put it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @cianius already has an answer. Nonetheless, this should be duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I am new at this and I was searching for the wrong term. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

`paste(df$ID,collapse=';')`